# spring Security + save information about connected user

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to develop a web project java jee ave the spring technology.
I would sauvgardement of information about the user logged in to my application (ipadress, when logged on disconnection) I use Spring Security.
someone has idea for this problem  and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to load the user profile in a Spring session scoped bean. For example:

```
@Component("profile")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String ip;

    ......
}
```

[Session scoped beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-global-session)

Spring security can also handle session management during logout. For example:

```
<sec:http>
    <sec:logout success-handler-ref="logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</sec:http>
```

Comment: i think u dont understand what i need, my application is with spring jsf and hibernate.
i have only a simple configuration in spring.xml